# WSAPoll vs Overlapped WSARecv Performance?

Tags: c++, networking, server, tcp, winsock

I'm creating a server that must handle 1000+ clients, the method I'm currently using is:

One thread will use `WSAAccept` to handle incoming connections, it has a threads pool of which each thread will handle multiple clients at a time using `WSAPoll`.

For example, if a Client has just connected, the Server will find a poller thread that is free and add it to the fdset of `WSAPoll` of that poller thread, thus the poller thread will handle the new Client connection.

The poller thread will use non-blocking WSAPoll to handle the connections, but then it will use (blocking) recv() to receive the packets.

```
Server: WSAAccept
    Thread Poller #1: WSAPoll [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  // max out
        recv[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    Thread Poller #2: WSAPoll [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] // max out
        recv[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    Thread Poller #3: WSAPoll [11, 12]         // free
        recv[11, 12]
    // create more pollers if all maxed out
```

It is working fine for me, but then I came across a (might be) better solution using **Overlapped socket with `WSARecv`**.

The idea here is to use a non-blocking `WSARecv` completion callback instead of `WSAPoll`

```cpp
    CompletionCallback(){ WSARecv(socket, CompletionCallback); }
Loop:
    socket = WSAAccept();
    WSARecv(socket, CompletionCallback); // CompletionCallback will handle the connection.
```

Therefore eliminating the need for multithreading and/or `WSAPoll`
I've made a PoC and it seems to be working just fine, but it is one-threaded, I wonder what's the performance of this compared to the old method.

Thanks!

Comment: As with all performance questions: You'll have to profile it and check if it's fast enough for your use-case. By only using a single thread though you'll inevitably run into a performance wall - there is only so much a single thread can handle in terms of raw throughput. The performance you'll get will depend on a lot of factors (how much data each connection needs to handle per second, how many connections will be active at a time, the hardware of the server, etc...) - the only way you can be sure it'll be fast enough is by profiling it.

Comment: In general if you need a truly high-performance socket server i'd recommend to use [I/O Completion Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports?redirectedfrom=MSDN) - they also work with completion callbacks, but instead of running them on a single thread you can have an entire threadpool dedicated to handling completions.

Comment: [AcceptEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-acceptex) is also really useful, because it allows you to batch up 3 operations at once (accepting the connection, getting local & remote addresses and reading the first block of data) - and additionally it uses overlapped i/o so it works perfectly with completion ports. (you can also have multiple pending `AcceptEx`'s against the same socket to prepare for burst incoming connection requests)

Comment: Thank you for the useful information, I've thought of using thread pool with this as well. Unfortunately because of my special need, I can't use any other frameworks and must write my own

Comment: FYI, [`WSAPoll()` is broken](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/10/10/wsapoll-is-broken/), so you shouldn't be using it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OVERLAPPED I/O scales remarkably well - scaling down/scaling up/scaling out. My tooling uses AcceptEx with OVERLAPPED I/O + Nt Threadpool. And it scales well to hundreds of thousands of connections. https://github.com/Microsoft/ctsTraffic